# In Xcode 9.0, how to open object definition in Assistant editor

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Prior Xcode 9, it was possible by pressing Cmd+Shift and left click on the object, but this is no more functional in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 9 now opens Action Menu when initiate Cmd + Shift + Left Click combination. Assistant editor can be opened by using right click instead.

Cmd + alt + Right Click

Comment: just cmd + left click opens the action menu. You can cmd + alt + rightclick to open in assistant editor, or cmd + alt + control + left click (where control + left click is the same as right click)